# No dot after year, when bib entry has no title

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

When an `@online` entry contains a note, but no title, I get a period after the year.
Even with `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}`
[image]

How to tell biblatex to not print the period, when no title is present?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authoryear,
    sorting = nyt,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @online{
        a,
        author = {Aristotle},
        year = {2015},
        title = {Geometry},
        url = {http://athena.com}
    }
    @online{
        b,
        author = {Knuth},
        year = {2015},
        note = {Computer Scientist},
        url={http://latex.com}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

% no dot after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\begin{document}

    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}` does not work is because `\labelnamepunct` is the separator between the year (or "author-year") in the chosen style and the title. However, in the standard driver for `online` there are several `\newunit` before the `note`  is printed. `\nounit` (or better `\newunitpunct` is the separator before `note`.

A "proper" solution would be to redefine the biblatex driver for `online`.  Alternatively, one can use the following hack:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {\iffieldundef{title}
      {\def\newunitpunct{\addspace}}
      {\def\newunitpunct{\addperiod\addspace}}
    {}
  }
  {}
}
```

This ensures that if there is not title, then `\newunit` produces a space. To restore the period (`.`) We can restore by including the definition in the formatting instruction for the `note` field in an `online` entry.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{note}{\gdef\newunitpunct{\addperiod\addspace}#1}
```

Eventually, similar definitions should be given for the `language` list and the `version` field, and the bibmacros `byauthor` and `byeditor+others`.

On the OP the hack produces:

[image]